# Reading an input file in __DATA__ format in perl

Tags: perl

I have this Perl code which has input data hardcoded in the DATA section:

```
 __DATA__
 M19,    Q,    P,
 M31,    M19,    Pl,
 M420,    M31,    E,
 M421,    M31,    E,
 M33,    M31,    E,
 M438,    M33,    Pl,
 M445,    M33,    E,
 M437,    M33,    E,
```

This hardcoded data is being processed by the following code:

```
 split /,\s*/ for <DATA>;
```

I have copied the data in a seperate input.txt file in the same directory as the code. But I want the file to be read as user input. But I dont know how to read the input file in same way as the `__DATA__` . Here's what I'm using, which isn't working:

```
print  ("Enter the file")
```

the user inputs `input.txt`:

```
chomp(my $file=<STDIN>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the filename entered by the user:

```
    print "enter the file name\n";
    chomp(my $file=<STDIN>);
    open(DATA,$file) or die "failed to open this file!!"; #this will open the file in the file-handle DATA if the file exists in the same directory else it will die
```

now you can split the contents by split function as you are doing like:

```
split /,\s*/ for <DATA>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the perl function [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

You can use

```
open(FH, $file);
```

to open the file and then process it with

```
<FH>
```

just like you did in split

Comment: Could you add some more detail to this response? An example of how to use `open()`, for example?

Comment: Edited the question and explained how to use it.